# Drop individual values from variable dependent on NA's in other variable

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with two variables and want to drop the values in variable B if the corresponding value in variable A is missing:

DF:

```
A  B 
1  1
NA 2
3  3
NA 4
...
```

Desired DF:

```
A B
1 1
NA NA
3 3 
NA NA 
...
```

I have tried something like this but it did not work:

```
DF[drop(DF$B) == is.na(DF$A), ]
DF[is.na(DF$A) == !DF$B , ]
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do :

```
df$B[is.na(df$A)] <- NA

df
#   A  B
#1  1  1
#2 NA NA
#3  3  3
#4 NA NA
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1L, NA, 3L, NA), B = 1:4), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```